# Workflow Based on Role

Tags: workflow, role-hierarchy

I want to execute the Worklflow based on ROLE. I had tested the same workflow with PROFILE it was working fine, but with ROLE not working

```
AND(($User.UserRoleId = 'PIP || BON'),ISCHANGED ( CloseDate ))
AND(($User.UserRoleId = 'PIP || BON'), ISCHANGED( StageName ))
AND((Owner.Profile.Name = 'User'),ISCHANGED( StageName ))
```

it was working fine with profile not working with ROLE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `UserRoleId` to `UserRole.Name`, just as you have done with `Profile.Name`. Your `OR` syntax is also not going to work. Use the standard `OR` function.

```
OR($User.UserRole.Name = 'PIP', $User.UserRole.Name = 'BON')
```